# Can you upcast a spell above 5th level as part of the Contingency spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The [*contingency*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contingency) spell specifies that you may only store "a spell of 5th level or lower" with it. However, it does not specify what spell slot level it must be cast through.

RAW, would it be possible to cast, for example, a 9th-level [*Melf's minute meteors*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/melfs-minute-meteors), seeing as how the spell itself is only 3rd level?

Comment: Related: [Is a 1st level spell cast using a 4th level slot a 1st or 4th level spell?](/questions/89932), [Does a spell cast using a 10th-level spell slot count as a 10th-level spell?](/questions/119432)

Comment: You have two different questions here. I'm going to remove the second one, but you can ask it as a new question if you would like. You can ask as many questions as you'd like, but only one per post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The spell is the same level as the slot used to cast it

The PHB says:

> Casting a Spell at a Higher Level
>
> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher
> level than the spell, **the spell assumes the higher level** for that
> casting. For instance, if Umara casts magic missile using one of her
> 2nd-level slots, **that magic missile is 2nd level.** Effectively, the
> spell expands to fill the slot it is put into. (PHB 201)

According to the rules, an upcast spell counts as whatever level the slot used to cast it was. There's no difference between slot level and cast level on a cast spell.

Thus, *melf's minute meteor* cast at 9th level is a 9th level spell and will not be able to be used with *contingency* because *contingency* requires that the spell, as cast, be 5th level or lower.

Answer (score 4):

#### You can use a spell slot up to 5th level.

When you cast a spell, the spell's level is equal to the level of the spell slot used. From the PHB (p201):

> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level than the spell, the spell assumes the higher level for that casting. [...] Effectively, the spell expands to fill the slot it is put into.

So you can use [*Contingency*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contingency) to prepare [*Melf's Minute Meteors*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/melfs-minute-meteors) at up to 5th level.